# Determine proper charger specs for a lithium-ion battery

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, charger, lithium-polymer

I have a device with a rechargable li-ion polymer battery but do not have a charger.

Device: ZTE WF723CA

```
Battery information
-------------------
LI-ION Polymer Battery
CAPACITY 2800mAh (10.8Wh)
NOMINAL VOLTAGE: 3.85V
LIMITED CHARGE VOLTAGE: 4.4V
MODEL: Li3928T44Ph735350
STANDARD: GB 31241
ZTE CORPORATION
MADE IN CHINA
```

What specifications should an off the shelf charger have in order to properly charge this battery.

Thanks

Comment: Looking at ZTE WF723CC devices, you don't need any special charger for it, the actual charger is embedded in the device. All you need to have is a AC-DC power supply that meets the WF723CC input requirement (plug barrel size and voltage), likely any +5V supply will do the job, the voltage is frequently shown on the case, or you need to find a user manual.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, everything charges safely at 1C. For your 2,800mAh battery, which is 2.8Ah, that means 1C is 2.8A, so make sure that your charger is 2.8A or less. Most generic USB chargers use a 1A or 500mA rate, so either should be just fine for your battery. Be careful of USB C chargers, which can deliver much more. One way to monitor any charger is to use a [Kill-A-Watt consumer power monitoring device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C4G7QVZT) or similar to tell you how many watts your charger is using. Probably much better is inline measurement, like a [usb power meter](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=usb+power+meter&i=tools&crid=1BTX0UJBZP3IJ), which you might be able to use. Full disclosure: I take no profit, and have no affiliation with either product that I have referenced.